# add/remove sibling elements attribute using jquery

Tags: jquery

i have this html.

```
<tr>
    <td width="75">Mon</td>
    <td class="bn_time" width="60">
        <input id="mon_open" name="mon_open" class="time" placeholder="opening time" />
    </td>
    <td class="bn_time" width="10" align="center">-</td>
    <td class="bn_time" width="100">
        <input id="mon_close" name="mon_close" class="time" placeholder="closing time" />
    </td>
    <td colspan="3" align="center" class="bn_holiday" hidden>Holiday</td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="mon_closed" id="mon_closed" class="bn_closed" />
        <label for="mon_closed">Closed</label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

what i am trying to do is using change event for checkbox `add/remove' hidden attribute to`` element. for example.

```
if ('#bn_closed').is(':checked') {
    //hide all <td> element with class bn_time
    //show <td> element with class bn_holiday
} else {
    //show all <td> element with class bn_time
    //hide <td> element with class bn_holiday
}
```

this is what i tried to do using jQuery.

```
$('.bn_closed').change(function() {
    var element = $(this);
    var id = element.attr('id');
    var day = id.slice(0,-7);
    var day_open = day+'_open';
    var day_close = day+'_close';
    if(element.is(':checked')) {
        //hide all <td> element with class bn_time
        //show <td> element with class bn_holiday
    } else {
        //show all <td> element with class bn_time
        //hide <td> element with class bn_holiday
    }
});
```

there is on important thing to note, **there are multiple  element with the same class name. i want to modify the attribute of  element of just siblings not all that is in the table.**

thank you.

Comment: do you mean `<td>` rather than `<tr>`?

Comment: where is `.bn_closed` in this table?

Comment: @hunter it is in the input of last <td> element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var checked = element.is(':checked');
var $td = element.closest("td");

$td.siblings(".bn_time").toggle(!checked);
$td.siblings(".bn_holiday").toggle(checked);
```

Comment: i have multiple `<tr>` this does not work on other <tr> elements. any reason for ths?

Comment: so sorry, it works. i had forgot to update the markup for the rest, it works. thank you :)

Comment: just one correction, `$td.siblings(".bn_time").toggle(checked);` should be `!checked` and `checked` for second.